# splitting iris dataset , showing error name 'y' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
     test_size = 0.2, random_state=1)
```

and the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbvWU.png) displayed is "name 'y' is not defined.

Comment: It would help if you format your question submission properly, and provide a better description of the problem - what are you trying to achieve, and what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the first 2 arguments for the `train_test_split()` function, they must be already defined, and their type must be one of the allowed types.
Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes.
Refer the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define X and y variable before call train_test_split() function. X is input and y is ground truth output.